# Return a non empty string from range of cells in Access 2016

Tags: ms-access, vba

So I have inherited an Access 2016 DB that needs some tweaking, and I need help as I am familiar with Access, but I am not the best (not by far, or at all) :)

The db is setup as follows: 
Data is linked to 4 SQL Server Databases that imports two tables from each db, one being Clients and One Being Prospective Clients (this is for lookup purposes as the client wants to do nothing manually). In the only table that is updated in Access, there are 8 columns, one being the Client and One being the Prospective Client from each SQL Database. Looking like this:

Highveld_Client | Highveld_Prospect | Eastern_Client | Eastern_Prospect | Northern_Client | Northern_Prospect | Africa_Client | Africa_Prospect

Each of these is a drop down box and looks up the right data. But this makes for a very tedious report (as you can well imagine). What I am thinking is to have a field update automatically based on which one of these fields is not empty.

What I need is, exactly, the following:

**Of the 8 fields shown above, only 1 will ever bill filled.
I need to automatically update a new field with the data from whichever one of these fields is filled.**

For the love of me, I cannot seem to find a place that will guide me properly on how to do this. I have spent days scouring tutorials and forums, and nada. I know that if i need this done, it will more than likely be a VBA Code, but then it's not going to happen, knowing me, I will end up deploying a nuclear missile or something disastrous.

Thank you in advance, you'll never know how much all your help on these forums helps, or is appreciated.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you want the following result: `Client | Prospect | Region`, where Region is either Highveld, Eastern, Northern or Africa?

Comment: Hi! No, what i need to see is just which one of these 8 fields had data in it. So in otherwords, I need a field to update, for instance, Client, with the data that is in either Client_Highveld or Client_Africa or Client_Eastern or Client_Norther etc

Comment: Please edit (see link below tags) your post and illustrate your point with example data as your explanation is not too clear.

Comment: Thank you, i have done that

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem without touching VBA, using only the power of SQL. Try the following query:

```
  SELECT Highveld_Client AS Client, Highveld_Prospect AS Prospect, "Highveld" As Region
  From MyTable
  WHERE Highveld_Client IS NOT NULL OR Highveld_Prospect IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
  SELECT Eastern_Client AS Client, Eastern_Prospect AS Prospect, "Eastern" As Region
  From MyTable
  WHERE Eastern_Client IS NOT NULL OR Eastern_Prospect IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
  SELECT Northern_Client AS Client, Northern_Prospect AS Prospect, "Northern" As Region
  From MyTable
  WHERE Northern_Client IS NOT NULL OR Northern_Prospect IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
  SELECT Africa_Client AS Client, Africa_Prospect AS Prospect, "Africa" As Region
  From MyTable
  WHERE Africa_Client IS NOT NULL OR Africa_Prospect IS NOT NULL
```